# Calling a Grails service from a groovy database migration

Tags: grails, database-migration

With Grails 2.3.9 I am trying to implement a groovy change within a database migration changeset. It uses a Grails service to generate a UUID.

The execution of dbm-update fails with "connnection proxy not usable after transaction completion" error.

The changeset:

```
changeSet(author:"sola", id: "gefc.currency.defaultGlobalBaseCurrency.v49") {
    grailsChange {
      change {
        def igs = ctx.getBean("idGeneratorService")

        sql.withBatch(20,
          "INSERT INTO core_setting_value " +
            "  (id, version, module, scope, code, " +
            "   string_value, boolean_value, long_value) " +
            "VALUES " +
            "(?, 0, 'gefc.currency', 'global', ?, ?, ?, ?)"
        ) { ps ->
          ps.addBatch(igs.uuid(), "baseCurrency", \
            "HUF", null, null)
        }

        confirm 'Base currency configuration (global setting)'
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fundamental problem was that the groovy code in the change interfered with the transaction management of Liquibase (which runs the changesets).

After the service method is made non-transactional, the changeset runs fine.